# With YAML CPP, after finding a yaml node, how do I update this node with a new key/value set?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

Say I have a YAML root node, and after iterating through this root node, I have found the node I am interested in. How can I update the key/value pair of this node?

```
YAML::Node oldNode = YAML::LoadFile("original.yaml");
YAML::Node insertNode = YAML::LoadFile("insert.yaml");
for(YAML::iterator yit = oldNode.begin(); yit != oldNode.end(); ++yit)
{
    //how do I update the key/value pair of *yit ?
    //I want to each *yit with the "insertNode"
}
```

Comment: Please be specific of what library you are actually using and make sure to provide a working example.

Comment: yaml-cpp is used here.

Comment: Ok, can you put together a Minimal Working Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In particular, what are `original.yaml` and `insert.yaml`, and then what is the resulting full YAML document you'd like after your modification?